# Submenu de ajuda está em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Faltou traduzir o conteúdo do dropdown de ajuda:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem boas questões, não deie-as se perder como comentários, abra uma nova para isso esse outra

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sobre partes do site em inglês](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/sobre-partes-do-site-em-ingles)

Comment: Se esta pergunta já contem a tag `status-pronto`, deveria existir uma resposta de um moderador a dar conta que a situação foi resolvida, no sentido de se poder marcar a resposta como "a correta" e fechar este assunto.